# Converting google analytics custom Dimension to Metric in DataStudio

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to create metric whith % of https sessions, like:

> content group 1 - 100 sessions - 25 % https
>
> content group 1 -120 sessions - 30% https

For this purpose was created:

1) Custom Dimension in GA session level: `https OR http`

2) in DataStudio

field in data source

```sql
SUM(CASE
    WHEN protocol = "https:" THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)
```

OR

```sql
CASE
WHEN protocol = "https:" THEN 1
ELSE 0 END
```

But I always get the output `1` or `100%`

Answer (score 1):

Is it not because you haven't divided by the total count?

```
SUM(CASE
WHEN protocol = "https:" THEN 1
ELSE 0 END)/count(protocol)
```

Comment: did not help COUNT(protocol) = 1 1/1=1 (

Comment: Maybe I do not understand how to add this formula in the field. if I insert so there will be an error

Comment: But over 100 sessions you should get a formula that brings back a result of x/100 where x is something along the lines of sum(0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1...,0,1). If you're only getting a count of 1 then you've only got 1 line of data?